# Linear Algebra Ordered Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ with ordered basis $B = (v_1,v_2)$, and let $v_3,v_4 \in V$. $A$ is the $3 \times 4$ matrix whose $i$th column is $v_i$. Find a $3 \times 2$ matrix $B$ and a $2 \times 4$ matrix $C$ such that $A = BC$.

We are talking about orthogonality in class and I think it has something to do with that. I understand matrix multiplication but have now idea where to start with this other than $A=BC$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$T : \Bbb{R}^4 \to V : (a, b, c, d) \mapsto av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 + dv_4.$$
Note $T$ is linear. Further, let
$$J : V \to \Bbb{R}^3$$
be the inclusion map from $V$ into $\Bbb{R}^3$. That is, $J(x) = x$ (like the identity map) for all $x \in V$, but with the codomain being a larger space than $V$. Naturally, $J$ is linear too.

Let $E$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^4$, $F$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$, and $B = (v_1, v_2)$, the basis given for $V$. We have
$$[JT]_{F \leftarrow E} = [J]_{F \leftarrow B} [T]_{B \leftarrow E}.$$
Note also that $[JT]_{F \leftarrow E} = A$, as transforming each standard basis vector by $T$ yields $v_i$, which $J$ includes in $\Bbb{R}^3$, and hence the $i$th column of $[JT]_{F \leftarrow E}$ is $v_i$. Thus, we can simply take $B = [J]_{F \leftarrow B}$ and $C = [T]_{B \leftarrow E}$.